# sshfs has no installation candidate

Tags: apt, package-management

Attempting to install sshfs on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS gives an error that there is no installation candidate, but there are dependent package available.

This package is available, so how do I install on Ubuntu bionic?

```
# apt install sshfs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package sshfs is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'sshfs' has no installation candidate

# lsb_release -c
Codename: bionic

# uname -a
Linux harbour 4.15.0-34-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Mon Aug 27 15:21:48 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: sshfs is in universe, enable universe and try again. https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/amd64/sshfs/2.8-1

Answer (score 3):

The `sshfs` package has been relocated to the universe repository:

```
# apt-add-repository universe
```

And re-attempting installation fixes the issue.